# What is the voltage drop across a wire

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

If we attach a resistor in series, most diagrams only consider the voltage drop across the resistors. What happens when we remove all of the resistors? Why does the voltage drop across the wire become not negligible all of a sudden?

In other words, why does the current passing through the wire suddenly decrease when resistors are added?

Comment: You neglect the wire's resistance because it is small against that of the resistors. If you remove all resistors, it's not "small" in any meaningful sense anymore, so why would you neglect it? I'm not sure what exactly the question is

Comment: essentially, how do the resistors 'steal' the voltage drop from the wire?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you remove all resistors the voltage drop will be across the wire. (Because the wire probably has a very small resistance the current through the wire will be very big and the wire will get very hot).

if there are resistors in series connected by wires, the resistance of the wires is usually neglected. You can easily see that this is reasonable because the total resistance, when the resistors are connected in series is just the sum of the individual resistances in the circuit. So, you add the resistances of the resistors plus the resistance of the wire and because when you add a very small number to a very big number, you can approximate that by only taking the big number. This is the reason the resistance of the wire is neglected. In many contexts this is not explicitly mentioned, but it is silently assumed that this is a good approximation.

Now the last part of your question. When you have a voltage across a wire and then add a resistor in series to it, the current will decrease. $I = \frac{V}{R}$. First we had almost no resistance and the current was very high. Then we add a resistor and the current drops, because the denominator increased. In the denominator we put in the $R$, strictly this is a sum of the resistance of the wire plus the resistance of the resistor, but here again we add a small number and a big number, so we just take the big number, namely the resistance of the resistor and we neglect the small number, namely the resistance of the wire.